# UITextView transfers the word from 2 characters for 2 lines

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have a chat table (correspondence)
The user text is in UITextView 
Problem in that on iPhone 4 if they settle down to enter 2 characters here so

[image]

And shall be so

[image]

The text is created as follows

```
-(NSAttributedString *)chatStringsMy:(NSString *)string
{
NSRange rangeBold = [string rangeOfString:string];

NSDictionary *dictBoldText = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0],

                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                           };

NSMutableAttributedString *mutAttrTextViewString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[mutAttrTextViewString setAttributes:dictBoldText range:rangeBold];

return mutAttrTextViewString;
}
```

On other iPHone models everything is normal.
How to solve this problem on iPhone 4?

Comment: issue is facing only on iPhone4?

Comment: @VvkAghera Yes (Maybe iPhone 4S) On all other iPhone 5 above (to iphone 6s) everything is good

Comment: width of Textview is auto depends on content right?